# Justify a Document object using itext pdf

Tags: java, itext, justify, pdf-writer

*I've added Chunks in a Document object*

```
Document document = new Document();
document.add(new Chunk("This is a text")); 
document.add(new Chunk("This is another text"));
document.close();
```

I tried to use the **setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED)** method but it looks like it works for paragraph only.

How can we justify the document object here?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, You need to use a Paragraph.
Both Chunk and Phrase don`t have the alignment properties.

Basically, font is the only "styling" property that is available for a Chunk object.
A phrase also has "leading".
A paragraph that extends the Phrase class is adding Alignment.

You can consider Paragraph as a CSS block-element and Phrase(Chunk) as inline elements.
Exactly as in CSS alignment is defined only for block elements.